# Irreducible representations of a group of order $p^4$ and exponent $p$

Tags: representation-theory

Background:
Let $G_1$ be the group of order $p^3$ and exponent p; one convenient presentation is
$$
G_1 = <a,x,y \, | \\
a^p = x^p = y^p = e, \\ 
ax = xa, \, ay = ya,\, yx = axy \,>
$$
It's not too hard to work out the character table of $G_1$; $G_1$ has $p$ conjugacy classes of size 1: $$\{ \{ a^n \}| n=0..p-1 \}$$ and $p^2-1$ of size $p$: $$\{ \{ a^n x^j y^k | n=0...p-1 \} | j,k \in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2/(0,0) \}$$. It has $p^2$ 1-dimensional representations $\rho_{j,k}$ with $\rho(a) = 1$ and $\rho_{j,k}(x) = e^{2i\pi j/p}$, $\rho_{j,k}(y) = e^{2i\pi k/p}$.
It has $p-1$ p-dimensional representations, all with trace 0 for the $p^2-1$ non-central conjugacy classes and trace $e^{2i\pi kn/p}$ for $a^n$ ($k$ ranges over $1...p-1$ as the representation changes). This is easily verified by the Schur orthogonality relations.

Now let's move to $G_2$ of order $p^4$ and exponent $p$, with presentation
$$
G_2 = <a,x,y,z \,| \\
a^p = x^p = y^p = z^p = e, \\ 
ax = xa, \, ay = ya, \, az = za, \\ 
yx = axy, \, zx = axz,\, zy = ayz \,>
$$
We go through the same analysis; $G_2$ has $p$ conjugacy classes of size 1 and $p^3-1$ of size $p$. It has $p^3$ 1-dimensional representations, given by $\rho_{jkl}(a) = 1$, $\rho_{jkl}(x) = e^{2i\pi j/p}$ etc.
Now we know that there are $p-1$ irreducible representations left over. We also know (by Schur orthogonality) that all of these representations must have trace 0 on the non-central conjugacy classes (the centralizer of a non-central element in $G_2$ is of size $p^3$). We *also* know that the sum of the squares of the dimensions of these irreps must be $p^4 - p^3$. The group $G_2$ has a large automorphism group, and it is reasonable to believe that all of these irreps should have the same dimension.
But that would imply that the dimension of these irreps is $\sqrt{(p^4-p^3)/(p-1)} = p^{3/2}$ which is not an integer.

So where have I gone wrong in my logic?

Comment: Note that $G_2/\langle a\rangle$ is elementary abelian. Since there is no extraspecial group of order $p^4$, we must have $|Z(G_2)|=p^2$. I believe that $G_2=G_1\times C_p$.

Comment: You are right; I missed it.  The center is actually everything of the form $a^m x^n y^{-n} z^n$.